# Why params does not accept generic types?

Tags: c#, parameters

Here is my scenario,

A function :

```
    public String StringConcat(params String[] parameter)
    {
        String l_strReturnValue = String.Empty;
        for (Int32 l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < parameter.Length; l_nIndex++)
        {
            l_strReturnValue += parameter[l_nIndex];
        }
        return l_strReturnValue;
    }
```

And i'm calling it like

```
        List<String> l_lstTest = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
        String l_strString = StringConcat(l_lstTest.Select(X => X).ToArray());
```

it returns the value as "ABC"

But its showing error if I call the function without type convrsion like

```
        String l_strString = StringConcat(l_lstTest.Select(X => X));
```

So how to use the function without conversion ?

**Note 1 :**

In XDocument `Add` method - they have used like `params`, but there is no such needs of  type conversions.

**Note 2 :**

The purpose of this post is not to add the strings, just want to learn more about the limits of `params`.

Answer (score 4):

The return type of `Select(X => X)` will be `IEnumerable<string>` - not an array. So you need another overload:

```
public String StringConcat(IEnumerable<string> parameter)
```

You'd probably make the array overload call this overload.

(And yes, obviously you'd want to use `StringBuilder` instead of repeated string concatenation - and `foreach` instead of a `for` loop.)

Note that the relevant `XDocument.Add` overload takes a `params Object[]` parameter, not `params String[]` - and LINQ to XML works such that if you try to add something which is itself enumerable, it's as if you added each item in turn. That's not part of the language - it's part of the implementation. So if you call:

```
doc.Add(someStringArray.Select(x => x))
```

that will actually just call `XDocument.Add(object)` which will *notice* that the argument implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you.... can you please post, why you suggested `Foreach` instead of `for`loop. `Foreach` is object type.... so it will more time as compared to the index type (`for`) loop ???

Comment: @Pramodh: `foreach` is a higher level abstraction - the code is cleaner, and expresses what you're trying to achieve more closely. In fact, a `foreach` loop over an array will use the array indexer anyway - but you usually shouldn't even *care* about the performance at that level of detail until you've found there's a problem. The performance of your code is *horrible* for large arrays, because of your use of string concatenation - any difference between `foreach` and `for` would be *nothing* compared with that inefficiency.

Answer (score 4):

The limits of the [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword is that the parameter must be an array type.

`l_lstTest.Select(X => X)` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, not an array, so it does not match the formal parameter type. It doesn't work for the same reason it would not work if you tried to pass a plain `int`.

To make it work, you should add another overload of the method:

```
public String StringConcat(IEnumerable<string> parameter)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of params by design, because if you were using

```
  public String StringConcat(params object[] parameter)
```

and you called with IEnumerable, you couldn't figure out if the parameter is a single parameter or it should iterate on the enumerable. For instance, without this limitation, in

```
  StringConcat( l_lstTest.Select(X => X) )
```

the IEnumerable should be an element of the list of parameters or it's the list of parameters?